# Symfony Voter constant usages

Tags: php, symfony, security, constants, symfony2-voter

I defined a voter, especially `voteOnAttribute` method like following :

```
 public function voteOnAttribute($attributes, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {

        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
            // return static::ACCESS_DENIED
        }
        if(!$subject instanceof PrivateResource) {
            throw new Exception('Media type mismatch : private resource expected here');
        }

        // Check company is elligible here
        if(!$subject->getCompanies()->contains($user->getCompany())){
            return false;
            // return static::ACCESS_DENIED
        }

        return static::ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
```

Why can't I use `VoterInterface` constants (`ACCESS_GRANTED`, `ACCESS_ABSTAIN`, `ACCESS_DENIED`) in my method ?

If I do so, the access denied decision is not enforced because of method `vote` in abstract class `Voter` :

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
    {
        // abstain vote by default in case none of the attributes are supported
        $vote = self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!$this->supports($attribute, $subject)) {
                continue;
            }

            // as soon as at least one attribute is supported, default is to deny access
            $vote = self::ACCESS_DENIED;

            if ($this->voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, $token)) {
                // grant access as soon as at least one attribute returns a positive response
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        return $vote;
    }
```

As `ACCESS_DENIED` constant is set to -1 in `VoterInterface`, the `if ($this->voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, $token))` condition is true, even if return is -1.

What am I mistaking here? Are those constants planned to be use in our custom `voteOnAttribute` methods ?

*Note : I set the voter strategy to `unanimous` in `security.yml`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I thought that I missunderstood the documentation.

But there is a difference in the documentation between the symfony versions

- extending Voter or implementing VoterInterface
  returning true or false
  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html
- implementing VoterInterface
  returning constants ACCESS_*
  outdated for symfony > 2.5
  https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

assuming you are using symfony >= 2.7 you should return boolean values in voteOnAttribute